# xgboost.cv returns an area under the curve less than 0.5

Tags: python, cross-validation, xgboost, auc

Running xgboost cross validation I get an area under the curve < 0.5.

I am running `xgboost.cv` as follow

```
best_params_grid_search={'base_score': 0.5,
 'colsample_bylevel': 1,
 'colsample_bytree': 0.8,
 'gamma': 0,
 'learning_rate': 0.3,
 'max_delta_step': 0,
 'max_depth': 3,
 'min_child_weight': 3,
 'missing': nan,
 'n_estimators': 15,
 'objective': 'binary:logistic',
 'reg_alpha': 0,
 'reg_lambda': 1,
 'scale_pos_weight': 1,
 'seed': 5,
 'silent': 1,
 'subsample': 0.8}

skf_inner = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_fold_inner,random_state=5, shuffle=True)

dtrain  = xgb.DMatrix(X_train,  label=y_train, missing = np.nan)

num_rounds = 20
cv_xgb4 = xgb.cv(best_params_grid_search,
dtrain,num_boost_round =num_rounds,folds=skf_inner,metrics={'auc'},seed=5)
```

but I get an AUC < 0.5. How should I interpret this result?

```
    test-auc-mean  test-auc-std  train-auc-mean  train-auc-std
0        0.402675      0.088828        0.777729       0.058559
1        0.390638      0.124389        0.890424       0.044356
2        0.418827      0.068236        0.932992       0.031358
3        0.448971      0.073219        0.946747       0.011304
4        0.460597      0.118598        0.956311       0.008302
5        0.437963      0.057661        0.970979       0.005968
6        0.461831      0.095017        0.978789       0.010346
7        0.422428      0.111894        0.977095       0.014329
8        0.419650      0.117329        0.983260       0.011606
9        0.433745      0.106113        0.989522       0.008979
10       0.440947      0.097941        0.992227       0.009497
11       0.449588      0.071629        0.994396       0.006438
12       0.429218      0.061360        0.995858       0.004400
13       0.455144      0.064862        0.998051       0.002757
14       0.443416      0.057515        0.999513       0.000689
15       0.440535      0.079628        0.999513       0.000689
16       0.446296      0.077557        1.000000       0.000000
17       0.450000      0.074674        1.000000       0.000000
18       0.468107      0.092640        1.000000       0.000000
19       0.451029      0.096165        1.000000       0.000000
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when it's unnormal to have AUC<50 because it mean, that your classifier works worse then uninformative classifier(random selector).Proof: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic 
Secondary, you model is highly over-fitted(train-auc-mean is 1.0).This mean, that you should make your algorithm more robust.